# Can I say "in age only"?

Tags: expressions

Does this phrase work?

> A senior in age only, he's never lost his strength.

It should mean that he's old, but you can't tell. It is meant to be a variation of "[in name only](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20name%20only)", although I can't seem to find it used. Will this work, or does it sound off?

Comment: *in years only* might fit.

Comment: [These Google 3-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+age+only%2Cin+name+only%2Cby+name+only&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20age%20only%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20name%20only%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20name%20only%3B%2Cc0) suggest that most writers avoid it ... 'in name only' is the favoured phrase.

Comment: It's much less common than "in name only" but that's not surprising and doesn't indicate whether it's valid or not. I think you're only going to get opinions, not facts - it sounds OK to me but some people might disagree.

Comment: What does the guy's strength have to do with what year he's in in school/university?

Comment: @aparente001 In the US, senior means an older person, as well as a 12th grade student.

Comment: @jimm101 - I guess so.  Maybe I'm behind the times.  When I see *senior* without *citizen*, I think senior in high school or college.

Comment: It's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an expression easy to understand even if you've never heard it before. Plus, I found some examples:

> Bichon frise Buddy's a senior in age only — [OC Register](https://www.ocregister.com/2016/03/11/adopt-a-pet-bichon-frise-buddys-a-senior-in-age-only/amp/)

> At this Party, a Generation Gap in Age Only — [Hartford Courant](https://www.courant.com/news/connecticut/hc-xpm-1999-05-13-9905130100-story,amp.html)

> Pitcher a freshman in age only — [SM Daily Journal](http://www.smdailyjournal.com/sports/pitcher-a-freshman-in-age-only/article_b269a9a9-ed76-5cef-a8bd-3e19fb783c66.html)